# Is there a way to clean all the old version of installed gems in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want my installed gems to have only last versions. Is there any way I could clean deprecated versions? Might it lead to unpredictable circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about `sudo gem cleanup` or you want to do with bundler?
with `-d` it will just show you what he might remove

`bundle clean --force`deletes any gem not required inside your Gemfile
bundle clean also just use the current gemset if you are using RVM

Comment: It doesn't matter what means to use.